# python socket not sending data in windows

Tags: python, windows, sockets, ssl, windows-10

I was trying to debug a library for opening ssl sockets in actionscript and encountered a problem with data not being sent through open sockets. I was able to reproduce it from python using this script:-

```
import socket
v=socket.socket()
v.connect(("127.0.0.1",443))
x='\x16\x03\x01\x00W\x01\x00\x00S\x03\x01O}\xb0\xb1Z\x9cv\x94\xd0\xec\x8e\xfc\xbd\xeb\xb9\x80isu\x19\x19\xa5\xd1o\xe1l\xcaU\xbb\xcb\xb6\xb5 \xf3&\xf6\xa0\xb3\xe6\x80\xb8\xdex\xa8\xdb)?\x91{\x1d\x03\xb0d\x1a1\xf9&\xedU\x96\x1f\xea|#\xb4\x00\x0c\x005\x00\n\x00/\x00\x05\x00\x04\x00\t\x01\x00'
v.send(x)
```

I had another python script listening for connections on `port 443`, any other string I sent, it was able to receive it, but not that string. Is there any restriction on what can be sent through a socket for the first time?

I am using windows 10 insider preview latest update. I haven't tried to reproduce the problem on any other OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that windows is monitoring all socket connections and I assume its detecting ssl connections, because the data being sent through the socket is just a simple client hello which has no extension data. And even though specifying no extension data in the hello is allowed, the program monitoring it is failing in such cases. After adding `\x00\x00` at the end of the message to specify the extension data has 0 length and changing the `\x00W` at the beginning of the message to `\x00Y`, it works fine.

I have checked the original code in previous windows versions and there it works fine.